# Optimize SQL query containing operations and subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, caching, subquery

I'm trying to speed up a SQL query which returns the 15 cheapest products with a given set of characteristics (width, height, diameter & load) sold by a few retailers. There are about 300k products in de DB. The total price is computed as the following:

> **totalPrice** = quantity*(price - discount*price)  + shippingCost

Where:

- **discount** (percentage) depends on the quantity ordered, the retailer and the time. As many discounts may exist from the same combination, the most advantageous percentage is selected.
- **shippingCost** depends on the quantity ordered, a few product characteristics and the destination where the product has to be delivered

My problem is that **discount** and **shippingsCost** depend on too many parameters to store each total price combination in order to make the query run faster. Consequently I think I'm stuck with subqueries.

---

Here is a simplified version of the SQL query, where the product quantity is set to 2.

```
SELECT `P`.*, `B`.`name_local` as brandName, `R`.`name` as retailerName, `D`.`amount` as discount,     `S`.`shippingCost`, ROUND(P.price * 2 + IFNULL(S.shippingCost, 0) - IFNULL(P.price * D.amount / 100 * 2, 0), 2 ) as totalPrice
FROM (`Product` P)
JOIN `Brand` B ON `B`.`id` = `P`.`idBrand`
JOIN `Retailer` R ON `R`.`id` = `P`.`idRetailer`
LEFT JOIN `Shipping` S ON `S`.`idRetailer` = `P`.`idRetailer` AND S.nbProduct = (SELECT nbProduct FROM `Shipping` WHERE nbProduct <= 2 ORDER BY nbProduct DESC LIMIT 1)
LEFT JOIN `Discount` D ON `D`.`idRetailer` = `P`.`idRetailer` AND D.amount = (SELECT MAX(amount) FROM Discount D WHERE (D.vehicle = P.vehicle OR D.vehicle = 0) AND D.idRetailer = P.idRetailer AND D.start <= 1451825895 AND D.end >=1451825895)
WHERE `width` =  '195'
AND `height` =  '65'
AND `diameter` =  '15'
AND `load` >= 0
ORDER BY `totalPrice` ASC
LIMIT 15
```

I'm using mysql 14.14. On my machine the query takes about 150ms to execute. By avoiding to use a current time timestamp for the discount, the mysql query cache may be better harnessed. But still, the query takes a quite long time to execute the first time and is quickly flushed from the query cache (due to the many combinations). Here is the result of the `explain` command on the query:

```
+----+--------------------+----------+--------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+---------+------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table    | type   | possible_keys                                 | key        | key_len | ref                    | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------------+----------+--------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+---------+------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | P        | ref    | idBrand,idRetailer,width,height,diameter,load | width      | 12      | const,const,const      | 13268 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | S        | ref    | idRetailer                                    | idRetailer | 4       | mydb.P.idRetailer      |     1 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | B        | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                       | PRIMARY    | 4       | mydb.P.idBrand         |     1 |                                              |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | R        | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                       | PRIMARY    | 4       | mydb.P.idRetailer      |     1 |                                              |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | D        | ref    | idRetailer                                    | idRetailer | 4       | mydb.S.idRetailer      |     1 |                                              |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | D        | ref    | idRetailer,start                              | idRetailer | 4       | mydb.P.idRetailer      |     1 | Using where                                  |
|  2 | SUBQUERY           | Shipping | ALL    | NULL                                          | NULL       | NULL    | NULL                   |    48 | Using where; Using filesort                  |
+----+--------------------+----------+--------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+---------+------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Is there an elegent way to speed up that kind of query or my only way is to improve the effect of the query cache (add RAM, increase cache size, etc.)?

Comment: 150 ms is pretty fast.

Comment: My other queries take less than 2ms each. The query is evaluated on many different web pages and each query increases considerably the Time To First Byte of the page. In addition the processing time increases with the quantity of products stored in the DB (I'm afraid it will reach half a sec in the futur). I'm trying to find a way to get at least below 50ms.

Comment: What are the inputs coming from the Web application? width, height, diameter, load? First three seem to be Product attributes, how about the last one?

Comment: width, height, diameter, load, quantity are coming from the Web app. width, height, diameter and load are columns from the Product table.

Comment: What about moving the subqueries to FROM section to let them be executed just once. At least the shipping subquery. Looks like it does not depend on P

Answer (score 0):

For the second (more complex subquery) try to LEFT JOIN with calculated discounts to let it be executed just once. Like this

```
...
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(amount) as amount, D.vehicle, D.idRetailer 
FROM Discount D 
WHERE D.start <= 1451825895 
   AND D.end >=1451825895
GROUP BY D.idRetailer, D.vehicle) D ON D.`idRetailer` = `P`.`idRetailer` 
                                 AND (D.vehicle = P.vehicle OR D.vehicle = 0)
```